# Concurrency problem with Redis in Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, redis, database-concurrency

### Problem

I have a key called `stocks` in my Redis and its value is 1000. Suppose 300 customers request to buy (100 stocks each) at the same time. In the end, only 10 customers should be able to buy.

### Solutions

I know it won't work but assume that my `buy` function is something like this:

```js
/**
 * @param {import("redis").RedisClientType} instance
 * @param {string} clientId
 * @param {number} n
 */
async function buy(instance, clientId, n) {
  // --- (1) ----
  // Get current number of stocks
  let stocks = await instance.GET("stocks");
  stocks = parseInt(stocks);

  // --- (2) ----
  // Validate if the stocks remaining are enough to be bought
  if (stocks < n) {
    console.log("error: company does not have enough stocks");
    return new Error("error: company does not have enough stocks");
  }

  // --- (3) ----
  // Update the current stocks of the company and log who has bought stocks
  await instance.INCRBY("stocks", -n);
  console.log("client @%s has bought %s stocks successfully!", clientId, n);
}
```

To test it, I wrote a function that calls the `buy` function 300 times:

```js
const redis = require("redis");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const { buy } = require("./buy");

async function main(customers = 300) {
  const instance = await redis
    .createClient({ url: "redis://localhost:6379" })
    .connect();

  // --- (1) ----
  // set stocks
  await instance.SET("stocks", 1000);

  // --- (2) ----
  // buy 100 stocks concurrentlly for each customer
  let pool = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < customers; i++) {
    let userId = crypto.randomBytes(4).toString("hex");
    pool.push(buy_v3(instance, userId, 100));
  }
  await Promise.all(pool);

  // --- (3) ----
  // Get the remaining stocks
  let shares = await instance.GET("stocks");
  console.log("the number of free shares the company has is: %s", shares);

  await instance.disconnect();
}
main();
```

Output:

```
...
error: company does not have enough stocks
error: company does not have enough stocks
error: company does not have enough stocks
error: company does not have enough stocks
the number of free stocks the company has is: -29000
```

As I said it didn't work but to fix that I used this approach:

```js
/**
 * @param {import("redis").RedisClientType} instance
 * @param {string} clientId
 * @param {number} n
 */
async function buy(instance, clientId, n) {
  try {
    await instance.executeIsolated(async (client) => {
      // --- (1) ----
      // Get current number of stocks
      let stocks = await client.GET("stocks");
      stocks = parseInt(stocks);

      // --- (2) ----
      // Validate if the stocks remaining are enough to be bought
      if (stocks < n) {
        throw new Error("error: company does not have enough stocks");
      }

      // --- (3) ----
      // Update the current stocks of the company
      await client.INCRBY("stocks", -n);
    });

    console.log("client @%s has bought %s stocks successfully!", clientId, n);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
}
```

And if you test it again you will see something like this:

```
...
error: company does not have enough stocks
error: company does not have enough stocks
error: company does not have enough stocks
error: company does not have enough stocks
the number of free stocks the company has is: 0
```

That means it works without a problem.

### Question

The above solution works well but I'm a little confused about `executeIsolated` function. As far as I know, it just creates a new connection (you can see [here](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/HEAD/docs/isolated-execution.md#isolated-execution)) and it's useful when you want to run your commands on an exclusive connection like `watch` command.

Who can explain what is the exact role of `executeIsolated` in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when there are concurrent requests there is no guarantee that the `SET` of the nth request will run before the `GET` of the nth+1 request. For example, in case there are 2 concurrent requests, the commands should be executed in this order:

```
> GET stocks
"100"
> INCRBY stocks -100
(integer) 0
> GET stocks
"0"
```

but they might be executed in this order:

```
> GET stocks
"100"
> GET stocks
"100"
> INCRBY stocks -100
(integer) 0
> INCRBY stocks -100
(integer) -100
```

In order to fix it you should use a [Redis function](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/functions-intro/) (available since redis 7.0) or [Lua Script](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/eval-intro/) that looks something like this:

```
local stocks = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])
if stocks < ARGS[1] then
  return redis.error_reply('company does not have enough stocks')
end

redis.call('SET', KEYS[1], stocks - ARGS[1])
return redis.status_reply('OK')
```

Regarding why the issue was "fixed" using `executeIsolated` - there could be 2 reasons for that:

1. the pool size is 1, which effectively creates a queue
2. there were no "idle" connections in the pool, and the time it takes to create a new connection is more than the time it takes to execute `GET`..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using functions for these types of issues too.
But about how the issue was fixed using `executeIsolated` you're right. If I set the `max pool` to a number greater than 1 the problem comes back again.